# get a variable into username and password auth?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
e = Entry(window, width=20, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=7, column=0)
username = e.get()
e = Entry(window, width=20, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=9, column=0)
password = e.get()


async def run(username, password):
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    data = {
        'client_id': 'XXX',
        'nonce': '1',
        'redirect_uri': 'XXX',
        'response_type': 'token id_token',
    }
    await session.post('XXX', json=data)

    data = {
        'type': 'auth',
        'username': 'insert username here',
        'password': 'insert password here'
    }
```

is there a way to put variables instead of strings?

i've tried this:

```
data = {
        'type': 'auth',
        'username': str(username),
        'password': str(password)
    }
```

but doesn't work correctly

im trying to use tkinter to enter a username and password into a variable that is added to this auth.

Comment: You're putting the username and password into `data` after you call `session.post()`.

Comment: How are you calling `run()`?

Comment: You're setting `username` and `password` when you create the form, not when the user fills in the entries.